# sql grouping... thing

Tags: sql

I have this data:

```
ID  Country   City    Type   Qty    SomeDate    SomeDate1    SomeDate2
1   Canada    Ontario Type1  1      01/01/2009  02/02/2009   03/03/2009
2   Canada    Ontario Type2  1      01/01/2009  02/02/2009   03/03/2009
3   Germany   Berlin  Type1  1      03/01/2007  02/01/2008   04/03/2006
4   Germany   Berlin  Type1  3      03/01/2007  02/01/2008   04/03/2006
```

I need the output as:

```
ID  Country   City     Qty    SomeDate    SomeDate1    SomeDate2
1   Canada    Ontario  2      01/01/2009  02/02/2009   03/03/2009
3   Germany   Berlin   4      03/01/2007  02/01/2008   04/03/2006
```

Dates between same cities are the same.

So, how?

Comment: Well that was simple. You should really consider learning SQL basics..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(ID),
    Country,
    City,
    SUM(Qty) AS Qty,
    MIN(SomeDate) AS SomeDate,
    MIN(SomeDate1) AS SomeDate1,
    MIN(SomeDate2) AS SomeDate2
FROM sourceTable
GROUP BY Country, City;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    MIN(ID),
    Country,
    City,
    SUM(Qty),
    SomeDate,
    SomeDate1,
    SomeDate2
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    Country,
    City,
    SomeDate,
    SomeDate1,
    SomeDate2
```

Comment: you will need all columns in selection list in group by clause as well.

Comment: @Faiz: that's not correct.  You don't include columns in the GROUP BY clause that you're aggregating on.

Comment: Yes, I should have said all non-aggregate columns in selection list. Apologies...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(ID), Country, City, SUM(Qty), MIN(SomeDate), MIN(SomeDate1), MIN(SomeDate2)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Country, City
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, Country, City, SUM(Qty) AS Qty, SomeDate, SomeDate1, SomeDate2
FROM Table 
Group BY Country, City, SomeDate, SomeDate1, SomeDate2
```

Comment: ID and Qty shouldn't be included in the GROUP BY clause because you're aggregating on these columns.